# Does entiymanager.merge() update cache?

Tags: caching, jpa, eclipselink

I call insert/update an entity using:

```
entitymanager.merge(entityclass);
```

But I select it using:

```
entitymanager.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Entityclass as o").setHint("eclipselink.cache-usage",
                                "CheckCacheThenDatabase").getResultList();
```

The result is nothing but the row still appears in database.

I want to insert/update an entity to database and it should be updated to cache for querying. How can I do?

I'm using ElipseLink 2.5

I added some configs to persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="Soft"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="1000"/>
</properties>
```